# DC-DC Buck Converter Issue

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

I made the below discrete two transistor buck converter. When NO load the output shows 5V nicely. Even a small 100mA load, the output voltage drops down.

How to overcome the issue?

Actually I need to convert 12V to 5V with a 600mA load current.

Thanks

[image]

---

Here is the Q2 collector voltage when no load.

[image]

Comment: Can you run a no load transient sim, and show us the collector of Q2? I have a very hard time believing this thing is toggling at all. You see ~5V thanks to D1 and Q1 but yeah, that's a pretty bad LDO.

Comment: I think you're simply expecting **too much** from this simple design. Did you know you can buy a **proper** DCDC converter which can do 12 V to 5 V at 2 A (so 500 mA will be no issue) for less than 2 US$, look for "LM2596 module". Sure you can try and "fix" this circuit but I have my doubts that it can be done without overheating and lots of issues. As an "exercise" this is a nice circuit just don't expect too much. I think if it can do 50 mA that's already quite good. Then again, it might just behave as a **linear regulator** so no switching at all.

Comment: I don't think it will switch at all.  I think you have managed to build a linear regulator with a filtered output using an inductor and capacitor as a low pass filter.

Comment: Actually, I can see how it might switch, but it certainly isn't self-starting and a simulation won't show it by default. Why does R2 have such a high value? You need to be able to saturate Q1 @ >1A peak collector current, so R2 should be no more than about 330 ohms, giving about 20 mA of base drive.

Answer (score 4):

Just an experiment:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQnd3X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, I've made two adjustments to the circuit:

- Reduce the value of R2
- Replace C3 with a resistor

With C3 as the feedback, the oscillation was very chaotic. Changing it to a resistor stabilized the oscillation at around 7.3 kHz. There's a nasty startup transient, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

[image: simulation plot]

Comment: I build very similarly circuit back in 2012 and it works very well. Here you have the "original"  design https://www.romanblack.com/smps/smps.htm notice additional capacitor instead of R5.

Comment: Hi, I build the circuit by doing the changes.I Reduce the value of R2 &
Replaced C3 with a 10K. Circuit works.Now with the load the output voltage is stable.But Q2 extremely getting hot.I loaded 150mA. How to solve that?

Comment: Put a heat sink on it? Seriously, you're asking a lot from a small transistor -- operating at around 350 mW, when it's only rated at 625 mW maximum. It's going to feel warm.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to explicitly model the ESR of the inductor. 2-3 ohms goes a long way toward taming that start-up transient. But it also means that the inductor is going to be dissipating a good fraction of a watt continuously, cutting into the overall circuit efficiency.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info.Actually I need to draw 600-800mA.I will change the transistor to a big one & see.

Comment: Hi I changed the Q2(BC327) with BD140, but it also extremely hot @ 500mA load.Any adjustments to be done..!!

Answer (score 0):

The DC resistance of your inductor seems to be high, so loading reduces output voltage. Use a high current inductor; the problem will be solved.

Check RomanBlack 2 transistor SMPS over net.